# How to avoid configuring all service classes in spring xml?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC for my project and in service classes i have used "@Autowired" annotations though i have to define all classes in bean tag in Application-Servlet.xml.(I feel its complicate if we have "N" number of classes) How i can avoid doing this?

Comment: I guess there's no way out since you need those classes to be instantiated by Spring IoC as 'beans'.

Comment: You shouldn't need to define any classes as Spring XML <bean.../> if using Spring 3.x. Could you please provide some sample code and more details as your question is too vague as it stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not clear which classes you are defining in XML config but I'll take a guess that you're asking about your service classes...

Simply annotate your service classes with `@Service` (or `@Component`). The [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection) will explain which to use and provides examples. Note: you'll need to have these lines of XML config to make this work: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar"/>` and `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Also works for controllers, simply annotate with `@Controller` ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)).

Comment: Yes i am talking about service classes. I used Service annotations in my service class though i have to define in xml as <bean  class="org.com.service.VarietyService"/> for each class.

Comment: You shouldn't need to define them as `<beans>`s. Do you have the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your XML file? Also turn on DEBUG level logging for `org.springframework` and you'll which classes are being instantiated by Spring on startup.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable reply. Yes i am using <mvc:annotation-driven /> but still i have to define bean tags. Schemas i have defined as follows    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd Do i need to specify any recent version?

Comment: I'd appreciate a "tick" next to my answer :)